# Memory sharing of persistent data structures in clojure

Tags: clojure

I have started learning Clojure and was reading about structural sharing. I am confused in the following scenario :
following clojure codes are typed in REPL in the sequence defined below :

1) `(def a [1 2 3])`,
2) `(def b a)`,
3) `(def a (conj a 4))`,
4) `(def b (conj b 5))`,

After the 4th step, will a and b share the structure for the first three elements or all values will be copied on the execution of 4th step ? If the structure is shared, how will Clojure be able to return us the value at say index 3 ?

This is somewhat related to [Structural Sharing in Clojure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8992184/structural-sharing-in-clojure), but I am still confused. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**In the example given in the question text, no structural sharing happens at all**. This is because vectors are implemented as trees, where the actual elements are stored in leaf nodes of size 32 (with the final leaf stored separately as the "tail" of a vector -- a performance optimization) and branch nodes are likewise 32-way. So, in order for structural sharing to come into play, one needs a large enough vector:

```
;; a base vector:
(def v1 (vec (range 31)))

;; no structural sharing -- all elements are copied:
(def v2 (conj v1 31))

;; leftmost leaf of internal tree uses v2's tail as its internal array:
(def v3 (conj v2 32))

;; leftmost leaf shared with v3
(def v4 (conj v3 33))
```

In general, whenever one `conj`s an object onto an existing vector, the new vector either (1) shares the entire internal tree with the original but has a new tail or (2) shares with the original, at each level of the original's internal tree, all nodes except the rightmost one (and may have an internal tree taller by one level than that of the original). (Clearly all the *elements* of the original vector are shared with the new one, however.)

As for looking up values by index, it happens in the same way in every case -- the vectors don't care whether their structure happens to be shared with other vectors (and there is no reason why they'd need to, given that it never changes).

Comment: nice answer. I wish there was a page with each basic clojure data structure explained in images. Lists are pretty obvious, but vectors not so much and being named like c++/java vectors, while being in reality a tree-based structures only adds to the confusion about them being persistent.

Comment: I am not sure about nothing is shared at all. Are you saying that even after 2nd step , a and b will share nothing ? Also, if after 4th step, if they don't share the data, then conj is almost O(n) operation, which is expensive.

Comment: @abhishekmahawar In terms of structure (as opposed to elements), `a` and `b` will indeed share nothing. This does not make `conj` O(n), since there is a limit on the amount of copying which may be performed (one array of 32 objects per tree level). It so happens that this mode of operation is very cache-friendly and with today's CPUs' cache sizes using arrays shorter than 32 wouldn't save you much time at all. Empirical evidence to support this assertion comes in the form of benchmarks in which vectors display excellent performance.

Comment: @abhishekmahawar There's a nice graph of index (lookup) and update times for vectors with various branching factors in Bagwell & Rompf's [RRB-Trees article](http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/169879/files/RMTrees.pdf); 8 seems to be the sweet spot for update (8 rather than, say, 2, which means that copying rather than sharing in your examples is basically an optimization!), while 32 gives slightly slower update, but faster indexing. On a different machine the results could have been slightly different, but the general shape of the graph would be the same.

Comment: @abhishekmahawar Wait, I think I misread your comment. After the 2nd step, `a` and `b` simply refer to the same vector. That's not structural sharing, though, which is about sharing parts of internal trees between different vectors; it's simply a case of giving the same value to two Clojure Vars. (You could similarly say `(def a (java.util.HashMap.))`, put some intries in, then say `(def b a)`. At this point `a` and `b` would refer to the same `HashMap`, but this would not be a case of structural sharing; in fact, this concept is simply not applicable to `java.util.HashMap`s.)

Comment: @MichałMarczyk - Scenario: I use an associative structure (map) as the accumulator of a `reduce` where I `assoc` something from each element being reduced. As each key (hash) is unique, won't I have a reference to the original map through all it's subsequent generations? This seems ok with reasonable counts but when I start thinking in the millions I wonder about the GC or just heap memory in general impact. Comment? (Kinda thinking I'd still have 1M elements somewhere in memory regardless of interim generations and bitpath/node back references).

Comment: @FrankC. Not sure if you're asking whether maps retain references to previous "generations" or whether a reference to the original map needs to be keep around while the `reduce` call is in progress, but either way the answer is no. Of course you're free to hold on to references to intermediate versions in your own code, and the original map may be passed to other functions besides `reduce` and for that reason be ineligible for GC before control reaches those other calls, but by itself `(reduce (fn […] (assoc …)) some-map …)` leaves `some-map` eligible for GC the moment the reduction starts.